# Using .next css selector in jquery where there are multiple elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a value *"Type de matériel"* stocked with a css selector in *COL*, here is my code :

```
<th nowrap scope="col" onmouseover="OnChildColumn(this)" class="ms-vh2">
    <div Sortable="" SortDisable="" FilterDisable="" Filterable="" FilterDisableMessage="" name="LinkTitle" CTXNum="123" DisplayName="Type de matériel" FieldType="Computed" ResultType="" SortFields="View={69d1eb84-0c41-4f10-93d3-4a0c2e62a646}&SortField=LinkTitle&amp;SortDir=Asc" class="ms-vh-div">
        <a id="diidSortLinkTitle" onfocus="OnFocusFilter(this)" href="javascript: " onclick="javascript:return OnClickFilter(this,event);" SortingFields="View={69d1eb84-0c41-4f10-93d3-4a0c2e62a646}&SortField=LinkTitle&amp;SortDir=Asc">
            Type de matériel
            <img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" class="ms-hidden" border="0" width="1" height="1" alt="Appuyez sur Maj+Entrée pour ouvrir le menu (nouvelle fenêtre)." />
        </a><img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" alt="" border="0" /><img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" border="0" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="s4-ctx">
        <span> 
        </span>
        <a onfocus="OnChildColumn(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" href="javascript:;" title="Menu Ouvrir">
        </a>
        <span> 
        </span>
    </div>
</th>

<th nowrap scope="col" onmouseover="OnChildColumn(this)" class="ms-vh2">
    <div Sortable="" SortDisable="" FilterDisable="" Filterable="" FilterDisableMessage="" name="Provenance" CTXNum="123" DisplayName="Provenance" FieldType="Text" ResultType="" SortFields="View={69d1eb84-0c41-4f10-93d3-4a0c2e62a646}&SortField=Provenance&amp;SortDir=Asc" class="ms-vh-div">
        <a id="diidSortProvenance" onfocus="OnFocusFilter(this)" href="javascript: " onclick="javascript:return OnClickFilter(this,event);" SortingFields="View={69d1eb84-0c41-4f10-93d3-4a0c2e62a646}&SortField=Provenance&amp;SortDir=Asc">
            Provenance
            <img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" class="ms-hidden" border="0" width="1" height="1" alt="Appuyez sur Maj+Entrée pour ouvrir le menu (nouvelle fenêtre)." />
        </a>
        <img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" alt="" border="0" />
        <img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" border="0" alt="" /></div>
```

Like that :

```
var elem_title="th.ms-vh2 div a#diidSortLinkTitle";
var COL=$(elem_title).text();
```

I get `COL = "Type de matériel"`

I would like to have COL = "Provenance", based on the previous value of COL I gave you.

I've tried to work with .next, or tried to do .text after the .next :

```
var COL="th.ms-vh2 div a#diidSortLinkTitle";
COL=$(COL).next().text();
```

But it doesn't work, the .text() gives me nothing.

Can you help me making work this .next?

Comment: Your selector is wrong  it will look next element of your anchor tag( "th.ms-vh2 div a#diidSortLinkTitle")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("th.ms-vh2:eq(0) div a").text();       //First value
$("th.ms-vh2:eq(1) div a").text();       //Second value
```

Comment: and do I use the .next()?